# Removing null values from dictionary with structure {column -> [values]}

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in this structure:

```
mydic = {'pet': ['dog', 'cat', ''], 'Date': ['', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']}
```

desired output:

```
mydic = {'pet': ['dog', 'cat'], 'Date': ['Monday', 'Tuesday']}
```

Ive tried to use this code

```
mydic = {k: [elem for elem in v if elem is not np.nan] for k, v in mydic.items()}
```

With no luck.
Any help is much appreciated, I realize this may come off as an elementary question but havent been able to find anything online unfortunately.

Comment: that's not null it's an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not `nan` , that is `''`, so change your code to

```
{k: [elem for elem in v if elem is not ''] for k, v in mydic.items()}
Out[283]: {'Date': ['Monday', 'Tuesday'], 'pet': ['dog', 'cat']}
```